# cocos2d iphone game move to ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

i want to make my game universal. but when i try it on ipad, my background layer only covers 1/4 of the screen, but the sprites can go the entire screen. also the sizes of sprites are too small, didn't scale up. 
when i see the apple doc, it says i have to "if else" to detect device every time use coordinate. but there are just so much code to be modified. 
so is there any way to solve this? like just change in one place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make your game universal, You have to rename your resources to support the ipad size.. meaning : sprite-ipad.png

It is not suppose to scale up when you choose universal app.. You can to redo the sprites..

As cocos2d auto handles the coordinates of the sprites when it is on different devices, it should be all over the device..

If you do not wish to redo the images, you can just choose to build for iphone.. It would be able to scale up when the player downloads it on the ipad..

Comment: you mean i need to keep 2 copies of my png files? or just rename them but no need to scale them up? i build it for iphone, but when running on ipad, nothing but the coordinate system is scaled up

Comment: yea.. 2 copies.. means it should be something like: sprite.png(for iphone), sprite-ipad.png(for ipad) or even you want to support retina display, add 1 more sprite-hd.png.. Means 3 copies.. each different resolutions..

Comment: so will cocos2d auto recognize and select the file names or do i need to do device checking every time?

Comment: how did you know it? which book ?

Comment: oops.. my bad.. they said they would implement it in the near future.. I thought that implemented it already.. it seems like the only way now is:  if((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){load ipad} else {//normal};

Comment: i believe google is better than a book.. link is here.. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/13563